# Firefox v15.0 about:newtab inaccessible via the back button

Tags: firefox, history, browser-tabs

As of this morning I upgraded my Firefox to version 15.0. Or well, it did it for me. That's when my issue began.

I've configured Firefox so that when I open up a new tab via `Ctrl-T` that it loads the `about:newtab` page which was released in version 14.x(?). I use this functionality extensively. I visit a page from the `about:newtab` page, read it, press the back button and pick another frequent website from the display I want to visit.

However as of v15.0 the latter part is no longer functioning, after visiting a website from the `about:newtab` page the back button will not let me go back to the `about:newtab` page. Firefox acts as if that history entry was never there.

I've tried searching the release notes to see if this change was intentional or a reported bug, but I have not found anything related so far.

Is there anyway to (re)configure the new Firefox v15.0 to let me access the `about:newtab` page via a tab's history?

---

EDIT:

It appears that this only affects the initial 'visit' to the about:newtab page when opening a new tab, manually visiting about:newtab will register it as a history entry and allow it to be navigated to via the back and forward buttons.

So I guess this changes my question to 'How can I make Firefox 15.0 treat the inital page from a newtab as a history entry'.

Comment: Don't worry, version 16 will be out next week and we'll probably be at v.30 by Christmas!!!! :)  :)  
Any way, I would suggest uninstalling and moving back to v14 as it's so early there will be little support for a week or 2 (depending on how long you want to wait for). You may want to report this though for a quicker fix: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: @Dave Reported the bug at bugzilla, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786992. Will see what they do with it.

Comment: +1. I just switched to FF from Chrome (because Google Chrome started to insult me), and find it annoying that I cannot back to about:newtab.